# How do I go back to the previous view through a hyperlink in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have models (POCO entities) like `Student`, `Course`, `Standard` etc. I have corresponding controllers such as `StudentController` etc. I have a view `Index` for each model which displays the list of all the corresponding entities in DB. For example, `StudentController.Index()` returns the `/Student/Index` view. However, if there are no     Student records in the DB, instead of returning the `Index` view , I redirect to the `Empty` action method of the `Navigation` controller, i.e. `NavigationController.Empty()`, which returns the `/Navigation/Empty` view. This is done for all model entity classes.

Now, on the empty page, I wish to have a hyperlink to go back to the previous page. So I created an action method called `GoBack()` in the `NavigationController` class, in which I redirect to the previous view. But how can I access the information about what the previous page was in this action method? Or is there a better way to do this? I do not want to use the back button.

Comment: If you're building an app-like site you may want to investigate SPA (Single Page Application) architecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned there are a couple of routes to take here. You could use sessions or the application cache to store a las visited page, and then get that page (by storing a route for instance) in the `GoBack()` action using a `RedirectToAction`.

But maybe a nicer and stateless aproach would be to render the hyperlink by having a view model having two properties for last used controller & action. Then you could pass these from the action result calling the `/Navigation/Empty` action (when there aren't any records).

**ViewModel**

```
public class NavigationVM
{
public string LastAction {get;set;}
public string LastController {get;set;}
}
```

**Navigation Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Empty(string lastAction, string lastController)
{
var vm = new NavigationVM()
{
LastAction = lastAction,
LastController = lastController
}
return View(vm);
}
```

**View**

```
@model = Namespace.NavigationVM

@Html.ActionLink("LinkName", Model.LastAction, Model.LastController)
```

**EDIT**

If you then need to find out from where the students controller was called (in your example) you can go about this the same way. I.e.: Render the link to the `StudentsController` with extra route values.

StudentController:

```
public ActionResult Index(string lastAction, string lastController)

{
     .... // no students
return RedirectToAction("Empty", "Navigation", new RouteValueDictionary(new { lastAction = "Index", lastController= "Student"}));

}
```

View with hyperlink to students controller (use the action and controller that rendered this view as `lastAction` and `lastController` respectively):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get students", "Index", "Student", new { lastAction= "Index", lastController = "CallingController" }, null)
```

Comment: Ok. This solution will let me make the `Go Back` hyperlink dynamic. But I will still have to pass the controller and action which took me to the `/Student/Index` action method, to the `/Navigation/Empty` method. Where do I get this information from?

In other words, when the `/Student/Index` action method is called, I need to know from where it was called, so that I can pass that information to `/Navigation/Empty` method.